# Retrieve the first HTML tag whos content matches search

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, lxml

Using: bs4, Python3.9, lxml

Say I have some HTML like this:

```html
<div>
    <a href="google.com">Item 3</a>
    <a href="facebook.com">Item 3</a>
</div>
```

I want to find the first occurance of the word `Item 3`, and get the specific `<a>` tag and the link that it's pointing to. How would I do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `.find()` method will return the first instance it finds. So just look for the `<a>` tag with the given text, and pull out the href attribute:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html = '''<div>
    <a href="google.com">Item 3</a>
    <a href="facebook.com">Item 3</a>
</div>'''


soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
item3 = soup.find('a', text='Item 3')['href']
```

**Output:**

```
print (item3)
google.com
```

Comment: This is the easiest solution, as well as the fastest

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.find` and `text=` property with lambda:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """
<div>
    <a href="google.com">Item 3</a>
    <a href="facebook.com">Item 3</a>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")
to_search = "Item 3"

tag = soup.find(text=lambda t: to_search in t).parent
print(tag)
```

Prints:

```
<a href="google.com">Item 3</a>
```

---

Or: Using CSS selector:

```py
a = soup.select_one('a:-soup-contains("Item 3")')
print(a)
print(a["href"])
```

Prints:

```
<a href="google.com">Item 3</a>
google.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using xpath:

```
from lxml import etree
root = etree.fromstring(html_doc)
e = root.xpath('.//a[text()="TEXT B"]')
```

Output:

```
print(e.text)
TEXT B
```